# In Polylang plugin, how to find the action/filter hook that runs on flag change?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, action, polylang

I have a bi-lingual WordPress site(Spanish and English) and using Polylang plugin. My problem is with a page whom I want to keep same for both languages. This page has assigned Spanish as default language and switching language on this page cause redirection to home page. Can someone suggest any hook or filter that runs on language switch?

In Polylang documentation no such hook is mentioned.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.